# AVCaptureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer stops getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have an issue with the delegate method `didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection` of `AVCaptureOutput`.

It stops getting called within a second or two when I'm adding the sampleBuffer to a `CFArray`. If I remove the `CFArray` code, the delegate method continues to get called so I have no idea why the `CFArray` code is causing it to stop. I'd appreciate any help.

```
@property CFMutableArrayRef sampleBufferArray;

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Called");

    if (!self.sampleBufferArray)
    {
        self.sampleBufferArray = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
        CFArrayAppendValue(self.sampleBufferArray, sampleBuffer);
    }
    else
    {
        CFArrayAppendValue(self.sampleBufferArray, sampleBuffer);
    }
}
```

Console ouput:

```
// Session start
2015-06-15 13:06:07.264 App[22467:5897858] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.286 App[22467:5897858] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.289 App[22467:5897858] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.315 App[22467:5897895] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.366 App[22467:5897895] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.384 App[22467:5897895] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.411 App[22467:5897895] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.449 App[22467:5897858] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.480 App[22467:5897858] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.513 App[22467:5897895] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.546 App[22467:5897895] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.579 App[22467:5897895] Called
2015-06-15 13:06:07.614 App[22467:5897895] Called
// No more calls after this point
```

Comment: how do you create and start a session? how do you configure your output? have you tried to set an observer for `AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification` notification, does it occur? If you write to file, does `captureOutput:willFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:dueToError:` occur? can you provide some sample project that reproduces the problem? Provide some more info on your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is actually referenced in the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:), Specifically;

> If your application is causing samples to be dropped by retaining the
>   provided CMSampleBufferRef objects for too long, but it needs access
>   to the sample data for a long period of time, consider copying the
>   data into a new buffer and then releasing the sample buffer (if it was
>   previously retained) so that the memory it references can be reused.

Essentially, you need to keep the callback operation as simple as possible, and should you need to perform further processing on the frame passed to you in the callback, you need to copy it to a new buffer and perform the processing in the background. Also, Keep in mind that Core Foundation object must explicitly be retained and released.

A further consideration is memory pressure. Frames contain lots of data, retaining too many will cause your app to crash.

Comment: Wow you just saved me from a headache that was lasting for a month, Thanks!

Comment: @MDB983 could you provide some code example or tutorial? I'm struggling with this issue much time and can't handle sampleBuffer properly, I have SampleBufferDelegate stop triggering after I make some manipulations with sampleBuffer.

Comment: How do you copy it?

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta Read the OP's question again. The answer addressed his issue and no code was needed. If you're having a problem, post a question, and perhaps, if you ask nicely, someone might reply. This is not a free programming service!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with screen capture API, where CMSampleBufferRef passed with each captured frame. While I'm playing with it in Xamarin, I'm observing this same problem with the Apple provided sample app. The key points are: 1) each frame's surface is assigned to a CALayer to display in a preview view; 2) the capture queue depth is set to 3. In this case capturing hangs even in apple's sample. I tried to dispose all the objects included with each frame, but only increasing queue depth to 4+ helps. Would you advice any particular method of releasing such resources?

Comment: ...continuation... the docs are really unclear about how the OS knows how long I'm holding the buffer. In particular, does it rely on reference counting, or does it think I'm finished when I return from the callback? (in the latter case how does the apple's sample work assigning captured image to a view and then returning from the callback). Anoter observation is: if I don't assign the buffer to the view's layer, queue depth of 3 works. But I just don't get it how 3 frames queue may not be enough if I use only one at a time?

Answer (score 3):

I encounter similar issue in Xamarin(C#) iOS development. Use the following code to release the `CMSampleBuffer` if in Xamarin:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: This fixed this issue for me. i was using ```sampleBuffer``` to create ```UIImage``` then calling ```sampleBuffer.Dispose()```, but it was still causing dropped frames after about 6 captured frames. Using your solution fixed it for me. Thank you.